# The usage of 该 in sentences

Tags: meaning, difference

I still do not get how to use 该 in a sentence. For example,

就该吃饭了, you can just say 就吃饭了, can't you? 
How do you use 该 properly in a sentence because I don't get its purpose.

Comment: You can say 该吃饭了. Time to eat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

就该吃饭了 is missing a subject for example 你
=> 你 *(現在就)* 该吃饭了 You *should be* eating *now*

就吃饭了 is not grammatically correct, it's missing 要 and a subject
=> 我 *(就)* *要* 吃饭了 I *'m* *going to* eat

该吃饭了 is proper because it implies the subject to be I/You
该吃饭了 means I/You should be eating now, or Time to eat.

Answer (score 0):

I thought more along the lines of:

我们该吃饭了。我饿死了！

Just for fun, I thought I would try to say "我们吃该饭了。“ where 该 means "this". That does not sound good to Chinese ears I'm told! No! No! No!

We can say:
该公司
该电视节目
该工作

Why don't you like 该饭？？Why can't you put 该 with 饭 or 餐？